# LEGO Boost Windows application malfunction

Tags: boost

When I like to run an external driver, my LEGO hub is driving B driver when driven from PC (Windows 10 app installed).
When I try the same application using a smartphone it works as expected.

Have you encountered a similar situation?

Comment: Hi Xawery! I'm sorry but your question is hard to understand, so it probably won't be answered as it is now. Could you please post a concrete error message or a more detailed description of what is happening? A screenshot could be useful too. Or just have someone proofread your question if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is connected with that Lego stopped supporting and developing Windows application.

Comment: I was going to post this: the Windows app is out of date and no longer supported. You need to use a phone or tablet or switch to a third-party library.